# Gas Water Heater leaking water out of the temperature and pressure valve. Could the water pressure regulator contribute to the issue?

Tags: water-heater, gas

Edit...I do not have an expansion tank or pressure gauges.

The “leak” was water pouring from the valve due to pressure or temperature.  Lots of calcium build up on the “down” tube attached to the valve.

My water heater was draining water from the relief valve.  I turned off the pilot and the cold water.  It stopped.  there is calcium build up from a leakage.  I figure I need to replace the valve which easy enough.

I have also noticed loud noises when toilets are flushed and water is turned on. So now I figure that should be the water pressure regulator.

Would too high of water pressure cause the leaking in the water heater?

Comment: Do you have an expansion tank in your water system?

Comment: Do you have an expansion tank? Do you have a pressure gauge? [Or two - one before and one after the pressure regulator, but for the purposes of this question, one after will do.] If not, consider adding both an expansion tank and a pressure gauge. When cold water is heated it expands, and if it is constrained by a check valve or something that acts like a check valve (which a pressure regulator does) then pressure rises drastically. An expansion tank gives it someplace to expand into with much less pressure increase. tl:dr the relief valve is probably working exactly as it should.

Comment: If you do have an expansion tank, it may have failed and need to be replaced.

Comment: Was the T&PRV "leaking" as in the seals failed, or was water coming out of it because the temp or pressure in the tank is getting too high? i.e. is it properly doing its job or is it failing?

Comment: It appears you've created 2 different accounts (your edit shouldn't have gone to the review queue if you'd logged back in as yourself). [Click here](https://diy.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts) for instructions on how to get them merged. (I've voted to approve your edit, but it'll take one more vote before it shows up.)

Comment: If you are talking about me having 2 accounts, I only ever opened 1 and have no idea how to delete the other. I followed your instructions but I got lost in the ether and have no idea how to perform the required tasks. I only have 1 log in password.

Answer (score 1):

The T&P valve on your water heater should be "exercised", that is, lifted and allow water to flow from it at least once a year and should be replaced when bad. I, replace mine every 5-6 years just to be safe. They do not cost a lot of money and keep you safe. A stuck or frozen T&P valve can do a lot of damage. As others have said, if you do not have an expansion tank installed near your water heater, it would be a good investment to install one. If you want or need to check the water pressure in your home you can buy a pressure gauge in any hardware store or the orange or blue store that will screw onto a hose thread.[image] My 2 cents.